# What is the fastest method of efficiently calculating cosine similarity of one vector to many in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, cosine-similarity

Below is the code I'm using currently. I'm comparing vector consisting of 768 floats against 50k others, and it takes about 800ms. I'm assuming that there's a much faster implementation, either in C# or perhaps some package that I can use that does the calculation natively, but I'm having trouble finding it. Thanks!

```cs
// USAGE:
// vectors is IEnumerable<float[768]>
// vector is float[768]

    vectors.DotProductSum(vector) * 100)

public static float DotProductSum(this IEnumerable<float> values, IEnumerable<float> other)
{
    return values.Zip(other, (d1, d2) => d1 * d2).Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very fast solution, [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss), which in my testing was able to query 10s of thousands of 2048-float vectors in <5ms. I'm consuming it from .NET, so used the [FaissMask](https://github.com/andyalm/faissmask) wrapper library. You need a number of native dependencies to do so, which you can get by building the faiss repo. I haven't found a package with the dependencies included. Specifically, I needed:

```
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libgfortran-3.dll
libopenblas.dll
libquadmath-0.dll
faiss.dll
faiss_c.dll
```

After that, the code is very straightforward:

```cs
using var index = new FaissMask.IndexFlat((int)embeddingSize, MetricType.MetricInnerProduct);
index.Add(vectors);
var queryResults = index.Search(queryVector, 10);
```

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to get those dll files by building the projects from the source code. Could you tell us how we can get those dlls? Thank you!

Comment: I have found all the dlls except for faiss_c.dll. Could you send that over here? I am having hard time building faiss from the official reposioty.

Comment: You're right, that one is tricky. You can get most of the files with vcpkg (vcpkg install faiss:x64-windows), but not faiss_c.dll. I've uploaded it here for anyone who needs it https://github.com/palenshus/palenshus/blob/main/faiss_c.dll. Ideally, someone would create a public nuget package with all the Windows faiss native dependencies though!